# What is the best layout to use?

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to replicate this layout in Android:

[image]

Basically, I need a layout which allows me to control each square by using left/top values. Each square will be added dynamically, therefore each square will be a Fragment. What layout can I use? I've done this in .Net in a metro app using UserControls for each square, all added to a Canvas layout. What would be the equivalent in Android?

Answer (score 2):

You should go for **GridView**.

For Gridview child item, Use **Relative Layout** so that you can easily place TextView at center and Bottom Right of the Layout.

**Edit:**

There is an open source code in Github for Draggable and Rearranging GridView.

https://github.com/thquinn/DraggableGridView

Hope This help you.

Comment: I forgot to mention something. I will need to use animations to shift the squares to different columns or rows. Can I do this in a GridView? In other words, can I specify the position of each square using left/top?

Comment: IDK if this will work with GridLayout, but check this video. It makes Dragging and Rearranging https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BZIvjMgH-Q

Comment: @MassimoCacchiotti i edited my answer shared a Guthub open source code. Plz go through that one. Hope this help you.

Comment: A `FrameLayout` is probably better for the individual grids.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the feedback, I was finally able to get it working using a RelativeLayout and the following code to move each sub-fragment to it's specific position.

```
        // Set the default size using the LayoutParams object
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams par = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(Convert.ToInt32(this.Data.Size), Convert.ToInt32(this.Data.Size));

        // Set the left/top position using margins
        par.LeftMargin = Convert.ToInt32(this.Data.Left);
        par.TopMargin = Convert.ToInt32(this.Data.Top);

        // Apply the layout change
        this.View.LayoutParameters = par;
```

Note: In case anyone is wondering why this is C# code, it's because I'm using Xamarin with Mono-Android.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly create the first box in xml...
And inflate it in for loops
You can use Relative as well as Linear as per your choice.